# How can I update primefaces treetable with AJAX using h:commandButton?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm constructing a treetable to display data. I also have a text field and a button to update the data in the treetable. How can I update the treetable without refreshing the page?

I tried something like

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{treeBean.update()}">
    <f:ajax render="treeTableID" />
</h:commandButton>
```

but it didn't work. So what shall I do? Many thanks!...

Comment: Context. Context. Your question needs context. Your code needs context.

Comment: @kolossus I've added some details in my question... thanks!